# How to search for the exact match of string(s) using the windows `findstr` command?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, findstr

How to search for the exact match of string(s) using the windows `findstr` command?
For example: I need to find only the exact match the string `store` but not 
`stored`, `storeday`, etc.

The below command returns all strings, `store`, `stored` and `storeday`:

```
findstr /l /s /i /m /c:"store" "c:\test\*.txt"
```

Complete script:

```
set "manifest_folder=C:\Calc_scripts*.*"
set "file_list=C:\Search_results\Search_Input.txt"
set "outputfile=C:\Search_results\Search_results.txt"
(for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%file_list%") do (
    set "found="
    for /f "delims=" %%b in ('findstr /r /s /i /m /c:"%%a" "%manifest_folder%"') do (
        echo %%a is found in %%~nxb
        set "found=1"
    )
    if not defined found (
        echo %%a is not found
    )
))> "%outputFile%"
```

Comment: Put a space at the start and end of the string? eg. findstr /l /s /i /m /c:" store " "c:\test*.txt"

Comment: `findstr /R /S /I /M /C:"\<store\>" "C:\test*.txt"`

Comment: @DavyC : adding a space would not work because I am searching the string in a list of say calc scripts. So the string 'stored' would be in different variations (not just space) eg : "store" , ->"store"->, "store";, @function(store).. etc.. etc..

Comment: @aschipfl : I tried it, but it says none of the strings are found. Below the part from my script where I use the findstr, 'findstr /r /s /i /m /c:"<\%%a\>" "%manifest_folder%"' . Did I do it right?

Comment: @m.joe, without seeing your whole script and some of the input it is hard to debug.  We have no idea what those variables are expanding to.

Comment: Here you go..set "manifest_folder=C:\Calc_scripts\*.*"
set "file_list=C:\Search_results\Search_Input.txt"
set "outputfile=C:\Search_results\Search_results.txt"


    (for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%file_list%") do (
        set "found="
        for /f "delims=" %%b in ('findstr /r /s /i /m /c:"\<%%a\>" "%manifest_folder%"') do (
            echo %%a is found in %%~nxb
            set "found=1"
        )
        if not defined found (
            echo %%a is not found
        )
    ))> "%outputFile%"

Comment: Check the positions of the backslashes in the search string, it must read: `"\<%%a\>"` (`\<` and `\>` mark word boundaries, according to the help of `findstr /?`; most characters other than letter, numerals and `_` are considered as word separators)... And please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38857449/edit) and post your script there!

Comment: @m.joe you are supposed to edit your question with code updates.

Comment: @aschipfl : Thanks! it worked. How do I mark your answer correct ?(sorry, new to stack overflow)

Comment: You can't, because my "answer" is actually a comment. As soon as you [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38857449/edit) and put your script there instead of in the [comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38857449/how-to-search-for-the-exact-match-of-strings-using-the-windows-findstr-comman#comment65082226_38857449) and let me know, I can prepare a complete answer and post it as a real answer, which you could accept by clicking the green checkmark.

Comment: I formatted the code as you copied it as a single line only which is hardly readable; please check whether my edit truly reflects your script and let me know... thanks!

Comment: @aschipfl: That's perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

According to the `findstr /?` help, `\<` and `\>` denote word boundaries -- see the following excerpt:

> ```
> Regular expression quick reference:
>   .        Wildcard: any character
>   *        Repeat: zero or more occurrences of previous character or class
>   ^        Line position: beginning of line
>   $        Line position: end of line
>   [class]  Character class: any one character in set
>   [^class] Inverse class: any one character not in set
>   [x-y]    Range: any characters within the specified range
>   \x       Escape: literal use of metacharacter x
>   \<xyz    Word position: beginning of word
>   xyz\>    Word position: end of word
> ```

Hence you need to change your `findstr` command line like this:

```
findstr /r /s /i /m /c:"\<store\>" "c:\test\*.txt"
```

So in your complete script it should look like this:

```
findstr /r /s /i /m /c:"\<%%a\>" "%manifest_folder%"
```