# How can find exact match with findstr in for of windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, findstr

What the only thing I want to do is in a windows batch, to get output of a `dir` command with `findstr`.

If I knew this was the most complicated thing in life, I wouldn't try.

What I did is, first, write my command that I need its output:

```
dir /A D:\path | findstr mykeyword
```

But actually I need exact match of "`keyword`", so I found this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39235594/2536614

So, my command is now:

```
dir /A D:\path | findstr "\<mykeyword\>"
```

I have tried it and the output is what I want.

Then, how do I get its output in a batch file? Of course, the intuitive tries don't work. It must be complicated. So, I found this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10131068/2536614

A loop just to set a variable. Anyway, this brings another complication. Now I can not write `"\<mykeyword\>"` correctly, escaping the special characters, within, first `'` then `"`, in `For` command, as the anwser suggests.

I have tried this:

```
For /F %%A in ('"dir /A %path_to_look% | findstr ""\\^<mykeyword\\^>"""') do set res1=%%A
```

This returns nothing. `res1` is empty.

So, how can I find exact match with `findstr`, but within `For` command?

Comment: As your question currently stands, I'm not sure why you'd need to use `findstr.exe` at all. Are you trying to match an exact file name? and if so what about _(`dir "%pathtolook%\mykeyword" /A:-D /B`, or `dir "%pathtolook%\mykeyword *" /A:-D /B` or `If Exist "%pathtolook%\mykeyword"` or `If Exist "%pathtolook%\mykeyword *"`)_, or are you trying to find an exact directory name? _(`dir "%pathtolook%\mykeyword" /A:D /B` or `dir "%pathtolook%\mykeyword *" /A:D /B` or `If Exist "%pathtolook%\mykeyword\*"` etc.)_. **An unfocused question will not attract focused answers!**

Comment: @Compo, ok, actually what I am looking for is, if there is a directory with a specific name, and if there is, if it is a symbolic link or not. But I was afraid asking "how to find if dir is symbolic or not", since in other answers I see 32546238462387 lines of batch code just to find that! So, I begun to try something like DIR .. | findstr "SYMLINKD". Then I came up with this. I couldn't imagine that it was so complicated to ask windows if a directory is symlink or not.

Comment: Did you not read the usage information for the `dir` command, at the Command Prompt, i.e. `dir /?`. There is an option specifically for 'reparse points' Examples: `Dir "%pathtolook%\*mykeyword" /A:DL /B | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /ILXC:"mykeyword"`, or `Dir "%pathtolook%\mykeyword*" /A:DL /B | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /ILX "mykeyword"`.

Comment: @Compo The problem begins when I want to use the output of this command with a variable. Please see my question.

Comment: You don't need the _additional_ quotes in the commands inside a FOR /F. Try: `For /F %%A in ('dir /A %path_to_look% ^| findstr "\<mykeyword\>"') do set res1=%%A`

Comment: @Aacini I wish you read the question a couple hours ago :) This was just the answer! Thanks!

Comment: @MertMertce you essentially were on the right path to get the answer yourself.  Why you chose to use so many extra sets of quotes and escaping with the findstr character "\" and escaping with the cmd.exe character "^" was your main problem.  Where did you even find a remotely similar usage of a `FINDSTR` expression on the Internet like that. Always keep in mind the [KISS PRINCIPLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Comment: @Squashman you're right. In the question I have given the links from where I got those, evil in('" etc. I was wondering why a human needs to do ' and also " there. But it took me much time to find out ^|.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, to capture the output of the command line:

```cmd
dir /A %path_to_look% | findstr "\<mykeyword\>"
```

by a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html), you could use (note the [escaped](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) [pipe](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) `^|` which is necessary as it is exposed to the command processor unquoted):

```cmd
for /F %%A in ('dir /A %path_to_look% ^| findstr "\<mykeyword\>"') do set res1=%%A
```

or (with additional surrounding quotes, leading to the pipe to appear quoted but to the [redirection symbols `<` and `>`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) unquoted, hence requiring escaping):

```cmd
for /F %%A in ('"dir /A %path_to_look% | findstr "\^<mykeyword\^>""') do set res1=%%A
```

Knowing that `for /F` executes the given command by [`cmd /C`](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) and regarding its rules for handling of quotes (type `cmd /?` and read the usage text) may help to understand why this works too.

You may have noticed that the second method inverses the quotation status of the whole command line, but this can be avoided by escaping the outer-most quotes:

```cmd
for /F %%A in ('^"dir /A %path_to_look% ^| findstr "\<mykeyword\>"^"') do set res1=%%A
```

However, let me recommend to use this only in case the outer-most quotes are really necessary in order to avoid syntax errors in a few unusual situations.

---

However, there are several issues in the command line (let us stick to the first approach here), which I want to depict here:

- the (unknown) path is unquoted, which could lead to issues with some special characters, so better use `"%path_to_look%"` (assuming that the variable does not already contain the quotes itself, which would not be advicable);
- [`dir`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html), without its `/B` switch, returns more than just the file names (like dates/times, file sizes, and a header and footer), which you probably do not really care about, hence provide `/B`;
- `dir /A` specifies to list all items (likes files, directories, reparse points, even hidden and system items), though you are probably only interested in (unhidden and non-system) files, hence you perhaps want to use `/A:-D-H-S` instead;
- file names may also include white-spaces, hence you should specify the `for /F` option `delims=`; file names may theoretically also start with `;`, so `eol=|` might make sense (as `|` cannot occur in file names);
- file names are case-insensitive, and so should be the keyword search by adding `/I` to [`findstr`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html);
- you should use the quoted [`set`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) syntax in order to protect special characters;

All this leads to the following improved command line:

```cmd
for /F "delims= eol=|" %%A in ('dir /B /A:-D-H-S "%path_to_look%" ^| findstr /I "\<mykeyword\>"') do set "res1=%%A"
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution has been using `^|` instead of `|` only.

This makes it possible to use only `'` instead of `'"` inside `in()`.

So now I could write `findstr ""` without need of escaping `"` character, which was the only thing I was trying to find.

So,

**before:**

```
For /F %%A in ('"dir /A %path_to_look% | findstr ""\<mykeyword\>"""') do set res1=%%A
```

Supposedly `"` could be escaped as `""` but this code did not work.

So,

**after:**

```
For /F %%A in ('dir /A %path_to_look% ^| findstr "\<mykeyword\>"') do set res1=%%A
```

This does work.

(Though, in other words "*how can escape special characters when using findstr within `in ('""')`* question remains as a mystery.)

Comment: `For /F %%A in ('dir /A %path_to_look% ^| findstr "\<mykeyword\>"') do set res1=%%A` could be rewritten as `for /F %%A in ('"dir /A %path_to_look% | findstr "\^<mykeyword\^>""') do set res1=%%A`, though I would not recommend that…

Comment: @aschipfl Thank you! It is so good to know also this! I was wondering how I could write it this way. It does not matter if it is recommended way or not! In another ocasion I could need. Actually, this is the exact answer of the question. My answer is "another way" to do it.